# Node.js Run service only at a suitable time

Tags: windows, node.js

I made a service in Node.js which runs fine. But I've decided to make a change. Untill the time isn't between lets say 7pm and 5am, don't run the service - be in standby mode - or sleep.

Which command or method to use? Is there something specific for such cases?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You could either use the windows sheduling to start or stop the service at the given times or programmatically send "standby responses" by node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NodeCron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) does the Job for you.

You can also try [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to cron the jobs.

Thanks.